# Реализация вероятности движения блуждающей точки на Си

Tags: c, случайные-числа, теория-вероятностей

Друзья! Не могу додумать решение проблемы. Существует поле, по которому равновероятно передвигается точка. Задается это следующим образом:

```
int boundary = on_boundary(p);
int key;
if(boundary == 0)
    {
        key = rand() % 4+1;
        switch (key) {
        case 1:                             //движение вниз
            p->i++;
            p->area[p->i][p->j] = 1;
            p->area[p->i-1][p->j] = 0;
            break;
        case 2:                             //движение вверх
            p->i--;
            p->area[p->i][p->j] = 1;
            p->area[p->i+1][p->j] = 0;
            break;
        case 3:                             //движение вправо
            p->j++;
            p->area[p->i][p->j] = 1;
            p->area[p->i][p->j - 1] = 0;
            break;
        case 4:                             //движение влево
            p->j--;
            p->area[p->i][p->j] = 1;
            p->area[p->i][p->j + 1] = 0;
            break;
        }
```

где boundary определяет не находится ли точка у края.
Каким образом изменить движение точки, если хочется, чтоб она двигалась не равновероятно в любом направлении, а с определенной вероятностью P продолжила движение в том же направлении, в котором двигалась? Вероятность задаю в начале программы.

Comment: В сторону: rand()%4 может неравномерное распределение сам по себе создать. [Why do people say there is modulo bias when using a random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/4279)

Comment: @jfs: Независимо от того, какой stateless метод проецирования "широкого" целочисленного диапазона на "узкий" целочисленный диапазон используется, он будет обладать bias, если ширина "широкого" диапазона не делится нацело на ширину "узкого". Поэтому называть этот bias "modulo bias" и ожидать, что присущ только оператору `%`, было бы неправильно. В рамках stateless методов проецирования невозможно избавиться от этого bias, независимо от того, какой метод вы будете использовать. Как вы ни выкручивайтесь, этот bias никуда не денется.

Comment: Когда целевой диапазолн намного короче исходного диапазона, этот bias будет ничтожным и пренебрежимым. Именно таковой является наша ситуация. Т.е. про этот bias можно смело забыть.

Comment: @AnT: к чему вы это сказали? По ссылке уже явно описано почему сломано и как исправить. Или вы просто решили перевести на русский? Для ясности: мой предыдущий комментарий буквально является правдой (я не думаю, что вы попытаетесь утверждать, что `rand() % 4` всегда равномерное распределение выдаёт)

Comment: @jfs: Я воспринял ваш комментарий как критику метода `% 4` и противопоставление его в плане bias методу `rand() / (double)((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1)` с последующей проверкой диапазонов, предложенному вами в вашем ответе ниже. Но ваш метод обладает тем же самым bias. Вот к этому я это и сказал.

Comment: @AnT 1- конечно, нет противопоставления :) Опять таки, решение по явной ссылке в комментарии использует `while` цикл с `(RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX % n)` пределом. Никакого отношения к моему ответу 2- Тема о распределении `x` из моего ответа интересная, но это уже отдельный вопрос. `x` в моём ответе double, поэтому напрямую "целочисленный" к нему не применимо. Не напрямую, конечно, нужно уже смотреть как double представлен: сколько double чисел от `0<=x<1`, насколько точно `i/(RAND_MAX+1)` как double представлен,  как соотносятся `1/(RAND_MAX+1)` с какой точностью `p` задано, etc

Comment: подробнее [Uniform random floats:  How to generate a double-precision
      floating-point number in [0, 1\] uniformly at random given a
      uniform random source of bits](https://mumble.net/~campbell/2014/04/28/uniform-random-float)

Comment: Ваша точка блуждает "неевклидово". Сделайте ей координаты с плавающей точкой, потом угол - через rand, шаг - через rand. В какой квадрат попала - тот и засвечиваете, можете антиалиасинг сделать.

Answer (score 3):

В такой постановке задачи удобнее думать о движении не в *абсолютных* направлениях - вверх, вниз, влево, вправо, - как в вашей нынешней реализации, а в *относительных* направлениях - вперед, назад, налево, направо - т.е. относительно прежнего направления движения.

На каждом шаге вероятность продолжения движения в прежнем направлении (т.е. вперед) должна быть равна `P`, а вероятности движения в каждом из остальных направлений - `(1 - P) / 3`.

Если у вас есть генератор `rand()` генерирующий целые числа в диапазоне `[0, RAND_MAX]`, то вам просто надо сгенерировать очередное случайное число `r` и проверить, например, попадает ли оно в дипапазон `[0, RAND_MAX * P]`. Если попадает - продолжаем движение в прежнем направлении, т.е. вперед.

В противном случае величина `r % 3` скажет вам, надо ли двигаться налево, направо или назад (относительно прежнего направления).

Answer (score 1):

Задайте значения вероятностей на каждом шагу p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub>, p<sub>3</sub>, p<sub>4</sub>. Одна - выше (насколько - решать вам) других и соответствует направлению движения на предыдущем шагу (задавать их придется на каждом шагу, потому что в начале программы вы не знаете, на каком шагу куда будет движение).
Все.
Их сумма, само собой, равна 1. Генерируем случайное число `r = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX` от 0 до 1. Все. Если `r < p1` - движемся в направлении 1, если `r < p1+p2` - в направлении 2, если `r < p1+p2+p3` - в направлении 3, иначе - в направлении 4...

Answer (score 1):

Если вероятность, что направление останется прежним равна `p`, то с вероятностью `(1 - p)` направление меняется на одно из трёх других направлений. То есть каждое из трёх других направлений имеет вероятность `(1 - p) / 3`.

Если сгенерировать случайное число `x` от нуля до единицы (`0 <= x < 1`), a тогда:

- условие `x < p` истинно с вероятностью `p` (отношение длины отрезка от `0` до `p` ко всей длине, то есть `(p - 0) / (1 - 0) == p`)
- условие `p <= x < p + (1 - p) / 3` истинно с вероятностью  `(1 - p) / 3`
- условие `p + (1 - p) / 3 <= x < p + 2 * (1 - p) / 3` истинно с вероятностью `(1 - p) / 3`
- условие `p + 2 * (1 - p) / 3 <= x < p + 3 * (1 - p) / 3` истинно с вероятностью `(1 - p) / 3`.
  Можно заметить: `p + 3 * (1 - p) / 3 == p + (1 - p) == 1`.

Чтобы узнать на какой из четырёх интервалов упала точка `x` на единичном отрезке, все четыре условия можно записать в виде одного цикла:

```
double p = P;
int direction_count = 4;
int previous_direction = direction;
for (int i = 0; i < direction_count; ++i)
  if (x < (p + i * (1 - p) / (direction_count - 1))) {
    direction = (previous_direction + i) % direction_count;
    break;
}
```

`direction` можно использовать как:

```
switch(direction) {
case NORTH:
// а мы уйдём на север
..
case EAST:
..
..
};
```

`x` можно получить так:

```
double x = rand() / (double)((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1);
```

См. [How to generate a random number between 0 and 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6218399/4279) Стоит упомянуть: не используйте `rand()`, если важна безопасность (для паролей или если игра на деньги): [How to generate a random number in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/822323/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Движение случайно блуждающей точки (броуновское движение) описывается уравнением диффузии. Если очень грубо, то скорость движения частицы прямо пропорционально коэффициенту диффузии и градиенту концентрации. Если рассматривать 2-мерный случай (ну типа капнули на салфетку краской и она растекается по салфетке), то концентрация частиц в идеализированном случае падает пропорционально квадрату расстояния от центра. Градиент концентрации соответственно будет пропорционален:

```
[градиент концентрации] = 1/R
```

Скорость движения:

```
[скорость движения]=D/R //D - коэффициент диффузии, R - расстояние от центра
```

В вашем случае по сути `D` задает вероятность движения частицы вдоль радиального направления. Если `D=0` то вероятность движения вдоль какого-то направления равна нулю.
Вам теперь нужно от полярных координат перейти к декартовым:

```
Vx=Dx/sqrt(x^2+y^2)  //скорость движения вдоль оси x
Vy=Dy/sqrt(X^2+y^2)  //скорость движения вдоль оси y
```

Остается наложить рандомное изменение координат `x, y`, задать вероятности `Dx, Dy` - движения вдоль осей `x, y`